# How do I use fill color for negative values in spider chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Is it possible format the Spider Chart so that the negative area is always filled with red color and the positives with green.

For clarification:

[image]

The color filling is done manually and if the values change to much it doesn't fit.

Comment: For clarification, the image is what you want it to look like?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this video - [How-to Color Radar Chart Rings in Excel](http://youtu.be/3YTNTSln0Hc).

Comment: @Raystafarian: That image is how it's currently looking. I can manualy edit the colors so it matches with the 0% ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel will do this pretty easily:

1. Create your data table with three series:  Maximum Positive (e.g. 4.0%) for each category, Maximum Negative (e.g. 0%) for each category and your values.
2. Create a Filled Radar Chart (Excel's terminology) using your three series.
3. Format the Axis to your appropriate minimum and maximum values.
4. Format the Maximum Positive series as green fill, the Maximum Negative series as red fill, and your series of interest as No Fill.
5. Format everything else to your preferences.

**EDIT:**  Engineer Toast brought up a good point:  make sure that your values series is the last one drawn (#4 in the samples below), otherwise it will be obscured by the other series.  Excel draws the series in order, with the highest number (or lowest in the dialog box list) drawn last.

Here's some samples of how it could look:

[image: Samples]

Comment: You'll have to be careful about the series order so that the line isn't covered up the filled series.

Comment: Ok, so it's only possible if I define min/max values so the chart stays the same. Thank you.

Comment: It's only necessary to define minimum and maximum if you want the bi-color scheme.  If the simple red circle would suffice (or the colored red center only), then you only need to define your "break-over" value as a series.  This series could be static or dynamic and could change across categories if needed.  If this value will always be 0, you could also use a formatted major gridline and not need the additional series.